# What's the English version of the German "oder?"

Tags: questions, syntactic-analysis

In German, you often add the question word *oder* after a statement (", oder?") to ask whether the statement's correct. What is the equivalent of *oder* in English?

I always begin sentences with this scheme and then don't know how to finish them. Must I change my question structure for such questions?

I know that you can ask whether a statement's correct by asking a negative like this:

> You were in school last week, weren't you?

With this, you also have to restructure your sentence in most cases

How about this?:

> You were in school last week, right?

Is this structure used often or is this just a bad solution to the problem?

Comment: Either sounds fine - I have a harder time finding a version of "ne?"

Comment: okay. "ne?" is just slang. some accent have it, some not. but in the end its the same like "oder?"

Comment: In most cases of spoken english, which is where this seems to apply, you could do without any clarification word at the end of the sentence. Intonation, especially vocal rising at the end of those sentences, would indicate that your statements are actually questions.

Comment: in this example above OK, there you just can raise the vocal. but what if you have this situation where you dont remember exactly what it was:
`A: Last week were holidays. You were in brazil?`

That sounds more like i just ask a random country where he could have been, but doesnt sound like i'm just not 100% sure if it was this.

Comment: I am not following how you "have to restructure your sentence in most cases" to simply apply a tag question. That is simply not true (as your very own example aptly demonstrates). Anyway, the one-size-fits-all tag question in English is *right*, or *innit*, as I am sure a good bilingual dictionary will be quick to point out. As it stands, I am not seeing how this is a question for this site. Translation questions are best taken to our chat.

Comment: Is it true (as the humorous stereotype suggests) that some Canadians use *eh?* for this?

Comment: @GEdgar: coming from Western Canada, I would use "eh?" more for questions leaning towards the rhetorical, or for a statement of fact which is meant to prompt a follow-up response. If I were to ask someone "You were in school last week, eh?" it would mean that I *knew/remembered* that they were meant to be in school last week, and thought for some reason that they might have something interesting to say about their experiences there or their feelings about it. Or I could ask "This is good beer, eh?" in which case it's like "isn't it?" in its rhetorical value.

Answer (score 4):

Google Translate says that "*Du bist ein Seemann, oder?*" means "*You're a sailor, right?*"

Therefore, I'd say that that *oder* means *right/correct* in this context. This translation is idiomatic English.

"*You're a sailor, aren't you?*" = "*Du bist ein Seemann, nicht wahr?*", according to Google Translate. That seems to accord with what I learned in German.

What do you think?

Comment: yes `oder` is used to ask if it was right/correct. so also english peoples use these methods?  `..., right?` - `..., aren't you?`

Comment: I don't know about whether this is true in German with _oder_, but _right_ often sounds a bit confrontational or at least brusque when tagged on this way. _, unless I'm mistaken._ or ... _, yes?_ might be gentler.

Comment: There are a lot of possible tags. Distinguishing between them is as hard as distinguishing between Gm _nicht wahr?_, _oder?_, and _na, und?_